# React possible to change scss variable?

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to override scss variables in react. I have for example a theme.scss with some scss variables. Is it possible to change these scss variables with the props of the Container. I know I could change `style={{ 
 backgroundColor: style.backgroundColor }}` into `style={{ backgroundColor: this.props.backgroundColor }}` but then the `$primary-font-color` would'nt change, because I set `$primary-font-color: $item-color;` in my theme.scss. Is it possible to OVERRIDE my scss variable `$item-color` so that also `$primary-font-color` change?

This is only some example-code to explain what i mean:

theme.scss

```
$background-color: white;
$item-color: gray;
$primary-font-color: $item-color; // I want to override $item-color so that also $primary-font-color changes
$secondary-font-color: darken($primary-font-color, 15%);

export: {
 backgroundColor: $background-color;
 itemColor: $item-color;
 primaryFontColor: $primary-fonty-color;
 secondaryFontColor: $secondary-font-color;
}
```

index.js

```
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Container 
        backgroundColor: 'gray,
        itemColor: 'black'  // I want to change my scss variable to this value
       />,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

Container

```
import style from '../style/_theme.scss';

class Container extends Component {
  render(){

  <div style={{ backgroundColor: style.backgroundColor }} >
    <div className='item' style={{ backgroundColor: style.itemColor }} >
      <p style={{ backgroundColor: style.itemColor }} >Some Text.. </p>
  </div>
  </div>

}
```

Comment: You generally should not try to manipulate styles with React, using CSS classes for this is a better option in most cases.

Comment: But I want to customize my style without replacing the scss file.

Comment: The short answer is no but it suggests an interesting idea (interesting to me at least). scss is compiled to a css file. Instead, it could be compiled to a javascript function. pass in the parameters and it would recalculate anything that needs to be recalculated (darken, etc) and return a style object you could pass to react.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comment manipulating CSS (SCSS so on) with React is generally not a good idea, because it will become hard to maintain. The preferred way to do this would be using classes, as they are reusable and more readable.

In your case what you can do is to define different theme classes, for example:

```
.whiteTheme {
    .backgroundColor {
       color: white;
    }
    .itemColor {
       color: white;
    }
    .primaryFontColor {
       color: white;
    }
}


.greyTheme {
    .backgroundColor {
       color: black;
    }
    .itemColor {
       color: grey;
    }
    .primaryFontColor {
       color: grey;
    }
}
```

And then manipulate the theme class name with React (this can happen only once, or per component, if you need it):

```
class Container extends Component {

  render() {
    <div className={this.props.isWhiteTheme ? 'whiteTheme' : 'greyTheme'}>
      <div style="backgroundColor">
        <div className='item' style="itemColor">
          <p style="primaryFontColor">Some Text.. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  }
}
```

P.S Naming props or CSS class `backgroundColor` is not desirable, it's just for general direction.

Comment: But then I can only switch between different themes. I want to customize  my Component with the props of the container. If I set for example the itemColor to green then the primaryFontColor should also become green

Comment: With your solution I can only switch between different themes, but I can't really customize my component

Comment: From my example, you can pass `this.props.isWhiteTheme` from the container component and manipulate styles accordingly. So my point is that you don't need to have a single global theme, you could have some component-specific themes.

Comment: But then I can switch only between them.. I can't pass this.props.iconColor green or blue to chang it to green or blue.. it's not that customizable

Comment: Well if you get only color names, you can pass them in CSS styles. Another option would be to conditionally load CSS files, something like this: `if(this.props.isWhiteTheme) {
            require('../style/_theme-white.scss');
         } else {
            require('../style/_theme-grey.scss');
         }`

Comment: @Shota Hard to maintain because the scss variable can be overridden by the component who is responsible for dynamic behaviour? Just make a section in the scss document with a comment stating that the variables are dynamic, or controlled by the component. In my opinion react components should be viewed as a controller for the styles as well. There are many use cases as to why you would wanna make styles dynamic. CSS will always be the static/default stylesheet. That doesn't mean you should scrifice possibilities for dynamic theming. You shouldn't be editing css if you don't know the component.